# Submit a URL as a file in a form

Tags: javascript

The scenario is: the user can input a URL for an image file, then on form submit I want to download the file and submit it to the server. As if they had selected the file using an `<input type='file' />`.

Of course I can just do it on the server-side. But my question: how can I do this on the browser side via JavaScript? Is it possible?

Comment: Yep, it's possible... `:)`

Comment: Okie, opened...